# Can I return a text value if a certain tag is found?

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am searching the following HTML with Beautiful Soup for certain keywords, when a keyword is found return the text contained in the next `div` with class `ds_data`. In my case the text is 1

This has worked fine, however a few of the divs contain an image with a red x to indicate 0. Is there a way of saying if an image of class `spacer_top n-sign` is detected then treat that as a text value of '0'?

**My code**

```
#HDMI
pattern = re.compile(r'\s*%s\s*' % 'HDMI ports quantity')
hdmi_ports = soup.find(text=pattern).findNext('div',{'class':'ds_data'}).text
print hdmi_ports

#DVI Ports
pattern = re.compile(r'\s*%s\s*' % 'DVI port')
dvi_ports = soup.find(text=pattern).findNext('div',{'class':'ds_data'})
print dvi_ports
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="tableRow">
<div class="ds_label">
<span class="tip-anchor tip-anchor-text"> HDMI ports quantity</span>ev
<span class="red line">
<div class="tooltip-text">
</div>
<div class="ds_data"> 1 </div>
</div>
<div class="tableRow">
<div class="ds_label">
<span class="tip-anchor tip-anchor-text"> DVI port</span>ev
<span class="red line">
<div class="tooltip-text">
</div>
<div class="ds_data">
<img src="/imgs/spacer.png" class="spacer_top n-sign" alt="Yes"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check whether the `<div class="ds_data">` element contains an `img` with those classes, using `find()`:

```
for search_text in ('HDMI ports quantity', 'DVI port'):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\s*%s\s*' % search_text)
    ds_data = soup.find(text=pattern).findNext('div', {'class': 'ds_data'})
    if ds_data.find('img', {'class': 'spacer_top n-sign'}):
        result_text = '0'
    else:
        result_text = ds_data.text
    print search_text, result_text
```

Output:

```
HDMI ports quantity  1 
DVI port 0
```

Comment: Hi Zero is it possible to just search for DVI port in that code above? I have a lot of other values to search for and would like to keep each search separated.

Comment: @Ninja2k yes, of course (although it would be a bad way to write your code - if you're writing almost-identical blocks of code for many slightly different situations, you're doing something *badly* wrong). It's trivial to use what I've shown above to do what you're asking, in any case: if you don't know how to do it, you need to read a Python tutorial.